# Databricks Bootstrap failure while creation of Cluster

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, terraform-provider-databricks

I've deployed Azure databricks workspace via 'azurerm' terraform provider and when I try to deploy Databricks cluster via 'databricks' terraform provider. I get this following error "Self-bootstrap failure during launch".

``Error: cannot create cluster:  is not able to transition from TERMINATED to RUNNING: Self-bootstrap failure during launch. Please try again later and contact Databricks if the problem persists. databricks_error_message: Self-bootstrap failure during launch. Please try again later a..., Termination info: code: SELF_BOOTSTRAP_FAILURE, type: , parameters: map[databricks_error_message:Self-bootstrap failure during launch. Please try again later and contact Databricks if the problem persists. Node daemon fast failed and did not answer ping for instance ]. Please see https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/clusters.html#clusterclusterstate for more details
│
│   with databricks_cluster.research,
│   on databricks.tf line 37, in resource "databricks_cluster" "research":
│   37: resource "databricks_cluster" "research"

I referred this [https://community.databricks.com/s`/question/0D58Y00008rCBTxSAO/databricks-cluster-startup-self-bootstrap-failure](https://community.databricks.com/s%60/question/0D58Y00008rCBTxSAO/databricks-cluster-startup-self-bootstrap-failure). But I didn't get exact idea. Could anyone please help me to identify the steps to resolve this?

Comment: Can you add more details (edit the question) on how workspace is configured - do you use vnet injection, private link, something else?

Comment: Thanks, Alex for looking this. Yes, We use Vnet injection. In fact, the issue is resolved once I re-deploy the Databricks workspace then Cluster was successfully created. Not sure how but Databricks networking is always complex when we are in customer tenant : )

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved once I re-deploy the Databricks workspace then Cluster was successfully created.